A proof of a form of the Poincare Lemma:
If $\omega$ is a closed $k-$current on the interior of $S_n:=\{x \in \Bbb{R}^n: 0 \leq x_i \leq 1, 0 \leq x_1+...+x_n \leq 1\}.$ Then $\omega = d \eta$ where $\eta$ is an extendible $(k-1)-$current or form in case $k=0$ in which case $\omega$ is constant.
I'd like to know if this proof is valid.
Proof:
We must show a closed $k-$current $\omega$ is of the form
$$\omega = d \eta \space ; \space \text{for some $(k-1)-$current $\eta$}.$$
Here $\eta$ is supported at the origin. First off if $\omega$ is a $0-$current, i.e., a distribution or a function, then we have
$$d \omega = 0$$
which implies $\omega$ is constant. So assume $k \geq 1$.
Let $\mathcal{L}_i$ be contraction with the radial vector field
$$x_i \partial_{x_i}.$$
Next supposing $k \geq 1$ we proceed by induction over the condition that there exists a current or form $\eta_j$ such that
$$\mathcal{L}_i(\omega - d \eta_j)=0 \space ; \space \text{for all $i \leq j$}.$$
For the first step, we may put
$$\omega = \omega' +dx_1 \wedge \omega^{''}.$$
Here, $\mathcal{L}_1\omega'=0=\mathcal{L}_1 \omega^{''}$ are a $k$ and $(k-1)-$ current or form respectively. Now $\omega^{''}$ may be considered an element of finite tensor product of extendible distributions of "functions" on $S_n$ with the vector space of differential forms with variables $x_j$, $j \in \Bbb{Z}^+$. Thus we can integrate $\omega^{''}$ in $x_1$. I.e., there exists an extendible form $\eta_1$ on $S_n$ such that
$$\mathcal{L}_1\eta_1=0, \frac{\partial \eta_1}{\partial x_1}=\omega^{''}.$$
To construct $\eta_1$ we extend $\omega^{''}$ to a compactly supported distribution then integrate from $x_1 << 0$, then restrict this new distribution back to $S_n$. If we set $\omega_1$ to
$$\omega_1=\omega - d \eta_1,$$
then
$$\mathcal{L}_1(\omega_1)=\omega^{''}-\mathcal{L}_1(\omega_1)(d x_1 \,  \wedge \omega^{''}+d^2\eta_1)=0$$
As $d^2=0$ and the rest cancel out, we have
$$\mathcal{L}_1(\omega_1)=0.$$
As
$$d \omega_1 = 0 = \mathcal{L}_1(\omega_1),$$
since $d \omega_1=d \omega - d^2 \eta_1=0-0$, we have that $\omega_1$ is independent of $x_1$ thus we may proceed by induction and so when $j>n-k$, we have that there is a $(k-1)$ current or form $\eta$ such that
$$\omega=d\eta$$
thus $\omega$ is exact as was hoped for.
